# Settimout not working inside For loop, acting weird?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, settimeout

Im trying to simulate a Typewriter effect with javascript. 
Theorically it should work with my code:

```
function TypeWriteToDoc(txt, id, x){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML + txt.charAt(x);
}

function TypeWrite(txt,id){
for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function() {
    TypeWriteToDoc(txt, id, i);
    }, 1000*(i+1));
  }
}
```

That should be it, when i call `TypeWrite("example", "p_test");` it should write each character of "test" in the "p_test" html. I think the problem its not on my code since when i call the function without using `setTimeout` it works like in the code below:

```
function TypeWriteWithNoSettimeout(txt, id){
for (var i = 0; i < txt.lenght; i++){
  TypeWriteToDoc(txt, id, i);}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You seem to say that your code doesn't work, but you didn't say what's wrong.

Comment: It doesnt work at all. The code above with the "setTimeout" does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with `var` in for-loops with callback functions.

The easiest solution? Just use `let` instead. `let` has support in [all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=let).

```
function TypeWrite(txt,id){
for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function() {
    TypeWriteToDoc(txt, id, i);
    }, 1000*(i+1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous response but rather than appending original text along with div.innerHtml, I adjusted it to be just the text char which simulates more of a typewriter feel. To increase the delay, I multiplied the index with 1000 rather than adding it since the larger increments are more visible.

```js
function TypeWriteToDoc(txt, id, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById(id)
    div.innerHTML +=txt.charAt(i)
  }, 1000 * (i))
 }

function TypeWrite(txt,id){
  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    TypeWriteToDoc(txt, id, i)
  }
 }
 
TypeWrite('example', 'p_test')
```

```html
<div id="p_test"></div>
```