# Why isn't this 'charAt' function working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a typing effect using Vanilla JS, but for some reason the `charAt` function isn't working, and when I replace `i` with something like 0, it works, but it spits it all out at once even though it's wrapped in a `setTimeout()` function

```js
var sentence = document.getElementsByClassName('sentence')[0];
var words = ['websites', 'apps', 'games'];
var speed = 100;

function type(word) {
  for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      sentence.innerHTML += word.charAt(i);
    }, speed);
  }
}

type(words[0]);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cursor {
  background: #000;
  width: 2px;
  height: 15px;
  animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  to { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sentence">We make </div>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example - possibly even dupe

Comment: Use `let i` instead of `var i` in the for loop and write `speed * i` instead of just `speed` as the second argument for `setTimeout()`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992706/settimout-not-working-inside-for-loop-acting-weird

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an "asynchronous" loop using recursion, because now you start all your timers at once:

```js
var sentence = document.getElementsByClassName('sentence')[0];
var words = ['websites', 'apps', 'games'];
var speed = 100;

function type(word) {
   if (!word.length) return; // Nothing to do
   setTimeout(function() {
      sentence.textContent += word.charAt(0);
      type(word.substr(1)); // call recursively only now
   }, speed);
}

type(words[0]);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cursor {
  background: #000;
  width: 2px;
  height: 15px;
  animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  to { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sentence">We make </div>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepted because of the use of recursion and because it's the shortest amount of code.

Comment: One question though. Why aren't all the timeouts created at once? Going by what I know from the other answers the timeouts should be created at once.

Comment: In my answer a timeout is only created when the previous one has expired. The difference is that then the timeout argument is always `speed`, while if you create them at once, you need to supply a different value to each of them (through multiplication).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure switching in this code block for your timeout will solve your issue. I haven't had the ability to test it myself though.

```
setTimeout(function(i) {
    sentence.innerHTML += word.charAt(i);
}.bind(this,i), speed * i);
```

Comment: This works but it's still being spit out at one time

Comment: That's because your speed is always the same. So all your timeouts trigger at once. Maybe if you can multiply speed by i you can increase the time for each subsequent timeout. I updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: what does the `.bind` do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use recursion so that each time a new letter is added to the innerHtml, it starts a new timeout. Right now it's creating all your timeouts at the same time so they all fire basically at the same time.

Comment: but why are the timeouts being created at once? I thought the timeouts ran,  waited for the specified time, then continued with the following code?

Comment: @JordanBaron `setTimeout()` starts a timer that will run the specified function once the time is up, but the rest of your code keeps running and doesn't wait for the timer to complete.

Comment: @JordanBaron the code first loops and creates word.length number of timers. All of these timers are set to go off in 100ms. So 100ms later, all of them fire almost at once (they are all slightly offset because it takes a very small amount of time to go through each iteration of your loop) and add their letters in.

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the speed as 100 is very low and you can't see it. "websites" is still loading in 800ms so it is hard to see anything.

Don't use "type" as your function name as this is a reserved jquery function.

This is how it works:

```
var sentence = document.getElementsByClassName('sentence')[0];
var words = ['websites', 'apps', 'games'];
var speed = 100;

function typewriter_string(word) {
  sentence.textContent='';
  for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      doSetTimeout(i, word);
  }
}

function doSetTimeout(i, word){
    setTimeout(function() {
      sentence.textContent += word.charAt(i);
    }, speed*i);
}

typewriter_string('websites');
```

In your code the "i" is always 8 because of the setTimeout in the for-loop.

Comment: I don't use jQuery.

Comment: Yeah but in every language you should avoid a method called "type". Added a working example.

Comment: Why should that be then?